# Sort Unity Launcher icons alphabetically

Tags: unity, .desktop, gsettings, launcher

I like to keep my locked Launcher applications sorted alphabetically, and I was wondering if it would be possible to write a script that sorts them, so I don't have to do it myself every time I add a new program.

If there is a folder somewhere that contains all the names and locations of the icons I should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: What is the language of your system? The most primitive sorting way is to make it sorted by the name of the `.desktop` file, a bit more sophisticated would be to sort by the "universal" (mostly U.S. English-) name, but applications might also have a localized name. To make it really neat, you (I)'d need to know the language of your system.

Comment: My language is set to American English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Keep the launcher sorted alphabetically

Running the script below in the background (see further below how to do that) will keep your launcher sorted alphabetically from a to z:

The top three launcher items before running the script: *Gnome-terminal, Virtualbox, LibreOffice*

[image]

Running the script: *dconf-editor, Files, Firefox*

[image]

#### What the script does

The (interface-) names of the applications is defined in `.desktop` files. These files can be stored in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. The latter "overrules" the global one, if the local one exists.

The script checks for changes in the launcher list, running (in a loop, every two seconds) the command:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

This returns a list of launcher items, ordered like the current order of the launcher.

If the launcher changes (e.g. if you add a new launcher), the script looks up the referring interface names in the `.desktop` files (preserving the precedence of the local `.desktop` files) and sorts the launcher items, according to these interface-names.

Subsequently, the script sets the sorted launcher by the command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "<sorted_launcheritems_list>"
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `sort_launcher.py`
2. Test-run it by running (in a terminal) the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/sort_launcher.py
   ```
3. If it works fine, add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&python3 /path/to/sort_launcher.py"
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time

home = os.environ["HOME"]
# define the two directories to search .desktop files, the string to identify application launchers
dir1 = "/usr/share/applications/"; dir2 = home+"/.local/share/applications/"; s = "application://"
# the key to read / write the launcher
lget = "gsettings get "; lset = "gsettings set "; key = "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites"

# read current launcher
def read_current():
    return eval(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", lget+key]).decode("utf-8").strip())

def sort_launcher(launchers):
    # split up launcher items in applications / others
    apps = []; others = []
    for it in launchers:
        apps.append(it) if it.startswith(s) else others.append(it)
    # create a sorted application (launcher-) list
    sort_list = []
    app_launchers = []
    for item in apps:
        check = get_interfacename(item)
        if check:
            app_launchers.append([check, item])
    app_launchers.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    # set the sorted launcher
    launcher_set = [item[1] for item in app_launchers]+others
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", lset+key+' "'+str(launcher_set)+'"'])

def get_interfacename(item):
    name = []
    for dr in [dir1, dir2]:
        subject = dr+item.replace(s, "")
        try:
            app = [l.strip() for l in open(subject).readlines() if l.startswith("Name=")][0]
            name.append(app)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        else:
            name.append(app)
            return name[-1].strip("Name=").lower()

# check every two seconds for changes, update launcher if necessary
current_launcher1 = read_current()
sort_launcher(current_launcher1)
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    current_launcher2 = read_current()
    if current_launcher1 != current_launcher2:
        sort_launcher(current_launcher2)
    else:
        pass
    current_launcher1 = current_launcher2
```

#### Notes

- The script sorts by US-English names of the applications
- In system monitor, the script shows `cpu 0%`, which means the script adds practically nothing to the processor load.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them using

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

and set them with

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites VALUE
```

where `VALUE` has the same format as what you've gotten from `gsettings get ...`