# Location of a new icon on the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

If I launch a program that has no permanent icon on the launcher, its icon appears there. However, it does not always appear at the bottom, but at a seemingly random location between the permanent icons. This changes the behavior of Super+Digit keyboard shortcuts, because some icons are now referenced by another digit - which is very annoying. How can I make new icons always appear at the bottom of the launcher?

EDIT: currently Ubuntu v. 15.10, although the issue happened also with 14.4.

Comment: Not literally what you asked for, but you can use this background script http://askubuntu.com/questions/593639/sort-unity-launcher-icons-alphabetically/594986#594986, which will keep your launcher sorted. The sorting orderis by the us-English names of applications. What you describe can be done as well though, but would take a new script...

Answer (score 0):

Well, my launcher does not place newly launched icons in random order, rather more precisely, it does not interfere with the top 10 (which are labeled 1-0) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0.  So, I must ask which version of Ubuntu, etc, etc, with more information on your part! Of course, if you by chance lock the new ones to the launcher and then move(click and drag) them around, you can upset the order easily.  Try dragging all locked icons to where you want them, with particular attention to items 1 thru 0.  Below those most cherished, place other important icons closer to the top ten, for convenience. Move them wherever best suits heck, even add em to the top ten if they grow in importance to your way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution was to just remove all locked icons (unlock from launcher) and then put them back and lock them. (Ubuntu 16.04.6)